Conditional expectation formula for having a sigma algebra and an event in the conditioning
For any sigma field $\mathcal{F}$, for any event $A$, and any random variable $X\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{P})$. Do we have the following type of formula resembling the formula where we only have events in the conditioning, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F},\textbf{1}_A)=\frac{\mathbb{E}(X; A|\mathcal{F})}{\mathbb{P}(A|\mathcal{F})}$? And I am wondering how to prove such equality?

We usually don't assume a formula  might be is correct because it resembles another. At least to the LHS you should give a rigorous definition. This could then answer the question by itself. (I won't spoil that exercise.)

@KurtG. Thank you! Then I think here we only need to check this equality holds on the generating set of $\sigma(\mathcal{F}, \textbf{1}{A})$, i.e. $\textbf{1}{A}\textbf{1}_{F}$ for every $F\in \mathcal{F}$. And we just play around with the characterising property for conditional expectation. Is this correct?

The formula cannot be true because the LHS is in general only $\sigma({\cal F},1_A)$-measurable and not ${\cal F}$-measurable while the RHS is ${\cal F}$-measurable.

$\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F},\textbf{1}_A)$ must be of the form $\alpha.\textbf{1}_A+\beta.\textbf{1}_{\bar {A}}$, with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, since those are the only functions $(\mathcal{F},\textbf{1}_A)$- measurables. We call these components $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F},A)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F},\bar{A})$ respectively. But:
\begin{gather*}
\mathbb{E}(X.\textbf{1}_A|\mathcal{F})=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X.\textbf{1}_A|\mathcal{F},\textbf{1}_A)|\mathcal{F})=\mathbb{E}(\textbf{1}_A.\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F},\textbf{1}_A)|\mathcal{F})=\mathbb{E}(\alpha.\textbf{1}_A|\mathcal{F})=\alpha.\mathbb{E}(\textbf{1}_A|\mathcal{F})
\end{gather*}
In short:
\begin{gather*}
\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F},\textbf{1}_A)=\frac{\mathbb{E}(X.\textbf{1}_A|\mathcal{F})}{\mathbb{E}(\textbf{1}_A|\mathcal{F})}\textbf{1}_A+\frac{\mathbb{E}(X.\textbf{1}_{\bar {A}}|\mathcal{F})}{\mathbb{E}(\textbf{1}_{\bar {A}}|\mathcal{F})}\textbf{1}_{\bar {A}}
\end{gather*}

Thank you for your answer, but I am not sure about your first sentence. Can you provide an intuition as to why this conclusion makes sense? Especially, why there's A closure?

Well, every measurable (real) function is a pointwise limit of simple functions. And the $(\mathcal{F},\textbf{1}_A)$- measurable simple functions  are of that form and therefore their limit.
